# How to make something similar to Visual C# 2008 properties window?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

What interests me is everything below the bar with buttons that determine how the properties are displayed. All I can figure out is there is a splitter and a status strip.

What I'm after is how there are 2 sections which I want to add the titles Property and Value, the sections can be resized with a splitter (I assume a splitter is used in this case), each property can be selected and the corresponding description appears on the status strip, and each value can either be text or a dropdown box.

The coding part I can probably do by myself, what I need to know is what controls the window is made up of and how it's put together.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are referring to the PropertyGrid control.  It's in the ToolBox.

See [Getting the Most Out of the .NET Framework PropertyGrid Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx)

Comment: +1 Btw, There are many other resources for using the PropertyGrid control. See here: http://www.propertygridresourcelist.com/

Comment: Oh I didn't know that existed, I don't know what most of the controls are..their names don't make any sense to me.

Comment: @TreeTree: When you're considering writing a custom control, like this PropertyGrid, it's always good to research whether or not it's been done. Microsoft does provide some good ones, like PropertyGrid, but there are also a plethora of open source controls on CodeProject, CodePlex etc.

Answer (score 4):

This is the [PropertyGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.aspx), and can be used directly.  There is no need to reinvent the wheel here...

Comment: +1 Btw, There are many other resources for using the PropertyGrid control. See here: http://www.propertygridresourcelist.com/